# How to get binary file from broker DB by BinaryDistributionModule?

Tags: dd4t, broker, dxa

On my enviroment, all binary files are configrured to be stored in Broker DB by cd_storage_conf.xml. Also, I'm using DXA(Tridion Reference Implementation).

Now, CSS, JS and generally used images are published by using "Get Design Element" TBB, and they are stored in Broker DB.Also, DD4T.Web.Binaries.BinaryDistributionModule is used to get binary files from broker DB.

But I cannot get binary files, and following message is output to Site.log.

```
DEBUG - Url /css/base.css does not match binary url pattern, ignoring it.
```

I saw a source code of BinaryDistributionModule, and this is because binary file URL is not matched with regular expression
defined by "ConfigurationHelper.BinaryUrlPattern".

What is "ConfigurationHelper.BinaryUrlPattern"?
And how can I confiure it?

Regards,

Comment: In your web.config, you can add a new key called "DD4T.BinaryURLPattern" and ensure that css is in the value

Comment: DXA does not use this property, see my answer for more detail on how binaries are managed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not sound like you are really using the DXA as this does not contain a *Get Design Elements* TBB, or use the standard DD4T Binary Distribution Module, or `ConfigurationHelper` class.

The DXA publishes design assets using the *Publish HTML Design* TBB. This TBB is executed when you publish the /System/Publish HTML Design page from your web publication (see [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-5A90868E-C260-4182-B323-6B9B7CE2BC7E)), and your assets end up in the broker DB with a path like:

```
/system/assets/css/main.css
```

The Sdl.Web.DD4T.Statics.BinaryDistributionModule takes care of serializing binaries from the broker DB to the filesystem and uses the `Sdl.Web.CommonConfiguration.MediaUrlRegex` property to determine paths for binaries. The path /system/assets/.* is automatically added as a pattern to this property on application startup.

Comment: It succeeded that publishing CSSs and images by publishing Publish HTML Design page, and BinaryDistributionModule works fine. By default it doesn't publish image and CSS files, so edit Gruntfile.js in html-design.zip(it's saved as MMC "HTML Design" in Tridion).Customize "copy:" section of Gruntfile.js and create folders and files in src/system/assets.Also the zip file must be unzipped in a folder on high layer (C:\work etc.), otherwise some files disappear and it causes publish error.

Comment: By default it certainly will publish CSS and image files, so I think something is wrong with your installation/customization